# How do I set what should happen in terminal on a certain command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, terminal, shell

If I execute

> cal 2013

in terminal, it echoes the calendar for the year 2013. For the matter of fun, I'd like the terminal to echo

> This year won't come.

How should I do this? I tried adding it as an alias to .bashrc, but I cannot create aliases with spaces.
Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

The final solution:

```
echo "cal() { if [[ \$@ > \"2012\" ]]; then command echo \"This year won't come.\"; else command cal \"\$@\"; fi; }" >> ~/.profile && source ~/.profile
```

Comment: Enclose the function definition in single quotes (`echo 'cal() {...}'`) and you can get rid of all the backquotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick the function in your .profile or .bash_profile

Note it is a function, not a shell script.  You can also just paste that into your shell prompt.  Putting it in a profile allows future login sessions to get that function defined.

Comment: One problem though, when I restart terminal, it doesn't work anymore, I need to do "source .profile" again. Any ideas how to make it permanent?

Comment: RiMMER: Hmm.  Your terminal must not be giving you a login shell, which is a bit strange.  You can put it in .bashrc then, which will be used for all interactive shells.